# Update Whole Column in one time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I searched web but couldn't find anything same to my need. I am using northwind sample database.

For example I have new prices  that came with excel sheet.

[image: My excel Sheet]

I imported to my database as new table named [Product Updates] and the column names are same as above[Product , New Price] and now I want to update products table to this new prices came with excel sheet.

I don't want to write 15 update statements. It must be done at a time with one piece of command I believe.

I wrote something like this

```
update Products 
set UnitPrice = [Product Updates].[New Price])
where Products.ProductName=dbo.[Product Updates].Product
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You code format sentence but don't code format code

Comment: Yeah sorry. I havent been asking anytihg for a long while. I am getting used to asking sth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple solution uses a `join`:

```
update p
    set UnitPrice = pu.[New Price]
    from Products p JOIN
         [Product Updates] pu
         on p.ProductName = pu.Product;
```

I would advise you to name things without spaces, so you don't need to use the square braces.  They just make queries harder to write and to read.

Comment: You are perfect. And thanks for advice.But did I ask sth that has already been asked why these negative votes for ? I searched couldn't find sth same with my situation

Comment: @UfukSURMEN . . . I don't know why the question would attract downvotes.  It has sample data, an attempt at a query, correct tags, so it seems reasonable to me.